# Does this look contaminated?

Tags: beer, contamination

This is the first all grain I made, it's a coconut porter and seems like some grains made it through. This is right before I transferred to my secondary fermenter, I know you can't tell much by only a picture but just an overall impression if this looks normal?

[image: Coconut Porter]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks fine, rack to secondary and grab a bit to taste if it tastes fine then you have most likely avoided any significant bacterial contamination.

Smell first, if it smells off don't taste it.
Taste it, if it tastes fine then it is good to go.

Comment: The foam is probably from the hops.  As mentionned, smell and taste will confirm everything.